# Android Life Cycle Issue

Tags: java, android

I am developing a flashlight application and I want to have it set up to where when the user opens the application, the screen brightness goes to full. I have set up a checkbox preference to do this but have a slight problem. See code below:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
     android:defaultValue="true"
     android:key="pref_brightness"
     android:summary="When checked, brightness will raise to highest level on main activity."
     android:title="@string/pref_5" />
```

> This is the checkbox code in the xml file for the preferences layout.

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
boolean box = getPrefs.getBoolean("pref_brightness", true);     
if (box == true) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness = 100 / 100.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
}
```

> And here is where I access the preference inside the MainActivity.java file. This is in the onCreate() method.

Now my problem is...when I open the application, the box is checked (unless altered by the user) and the brightness maximizes like it should. However, when I go into the preferences and uncheck the box, then press the "back" button, the box saves but nothing takes effect on the main activity. If I change the box and press the "up" button on the action bar, everything works great. Why is it not working when the back button is pressed? I tried using onBackPressed() but nothing seemed to fix this issue.

### **Update according to "Karakuri's" answer:**

> I did what you said and it still doesn't work right. If the box is unchecked and I go check it, press the back button, it works but then if I go change it back again, press back again, it doesn't save. Here's the code for your suggestion:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
boolean box = getPrefs.getBoolean("pref_brightness", true);     
    if (box == true) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.screenBrightness = 100 / 100.0f;
        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

Help is appreciated,

Andrew

Comment: In which lifecycle callback do you set the window attributes?

Comment: @Karakuri -- In onCreate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I just needed a full if statement like so:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean box = getPrefs.getBoolean("pref_brightness", true);     
    if (box == true) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.screenBrightness = 100 / 100.0f;
        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    }
    else{
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.screenBrightness = -1;
        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

Now this says if check box is checked, change the main activity's brightness to full but if it's unchecked, set the user's brightness to their setting.

Thanks to **Karakuri** for the help as well as **Nizam**!

Andrew

Comment: *(StackOverflow doesn't have private message function, otherwise I would have preferred that...)* Hi Andrew, As you've pointed out, I gave you the appropriate lifecycle callback and in comments suggested it was necessary to reset the value if the box was unchecked. While the finer details of that are interesting, I don't think that warrants selecting yourself as having posted the answer. I'd appreciate if you gave back credit for my answer...

Comment: I am referring to the reputation points. Selecting your own answer means others do not receive reputation for helping. Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The code that changes the attributes shouldn't be inside `onCreate()`.Try using inside `onStart()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you run this code in `onCreate()`, it will only get called once -- when the Activity is being created. You need to run it somewhere else. I recommend `onWindowFocusChanged()`. (You could use `onStart()` or `onResume()`, but those won't take into account the lock screen.)

Comment: You probably need to set it back to the original value. Right now what happens is you check the box, it runs that code to maximize the brightness. Then you uncheck the box, it runs the code again, but does nothing since the box is not checked. So the brightness never gets reset on that window.

Comment: Do you think I need an else segment too?

Comment: How would I set it back to default?

Comment: Well, I imagine you'd have to save the user's previous brightness setting and use that value if box is unchecked. I'm not sure how to get that value though...